# Libgdx Event Polling

Tags: java, events, libgdx

I am designing card game using LibGDX. A card can have effects which need to receive a player input such as the target of the effect. How can I "wait" for the player to select the target before playing the next effect?

Answer (score 0):

You install event listeners on actors, on a stage, or in your own input processor. Then you can run the event in for instance the "onTouchUp" or "onClicked" event